# adding event listeners in onCreate

Tags: java, android

I want to implement a `LocationListener`. Checked some tutorials and found this:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

 // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
          // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
          makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
      };

    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);


}
```

But are event listeners really added in the `onCreate` method? Looks pretty messy to me. Is it more common to add them to a separate class and create an instance of the class in `onCreate`? I would like to know the best practices here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is almost correct but step by step, there is no "good" reason to implement `LocationListener` in separated class but you should implement your `LocationListener` out of `onCreate()` method and

```
requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

is generally called rather in `onResume()` method and `removeUpdates()` in `onDestroy()` method.

I recommend to you check for example `WeatherPlus` application by **CommonsWare** and i think all will be clearer.

Comment: Stupid question i guess, but if i call the `requestLocationUpdates` outside of `onCreate`, how would i get the last argument, `locationListener`? Create it as a private variable in the class, and intialize it in `onCreate`?

Comment: it's simply, just create `LocationListener onLocationChange = new LocationListener() {};` normally outside of `onCreate()` as you would create normal method. and then simply call `mgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                10000, 10000.0f, onLocationChange);`

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want your application todo.
So first I agree that is looks messy in the onCreate().
Let's say you write a little init() method and call that from your onCreate(), nothing has really changed yet.
The only thing you have to pay attention to the Activity LifeCycle.
If your registering to receive location updates than your Activity may get updates when your don't have screen focus.
Another option is to move the register to onResume(), however you will need an unregister in onPause(). This will only get updates if your app is currently on the screen.

Comment: Ok, and when and how often is `onResume` called?

Comment: @Johan : In answer to your question WRT when/how often `onResume()` is called, see this explanation of how an `Activity` works and in particular the diagram for `Activity Lifecycle`. When I started with Android I printed the diagram out and stuck it by my dev machine... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: @Squonk thanks for that. Basically the rule of thumb is anytime your application is visually blocked (ie say by a Dialog Activity or the home button) then onPause will get called, once it regains full focus than OnResume will get called.

Comment: @FrankSposaro : No problem - I just happened by Johan's comment and had that `Activity` page open in another tab so it was easy enough to paste it in. As you say partial coverage by a `Dialog` will put the underlying `Activity` into a Paused state as will starting a new `Activity` which completely covers it obviously, - also potentially putting it in a Stopped state. In general the Resume -> Pause -> Resume cycle is the tightest of an `Activity` overall life-cycle and may be looped through many times.